# Retrieve Tab data from excel file via Google Drive API

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I need to access an Excel file's tab/sheet data and convert it into a dataframe without downloading it locally. I am looking for a method that retrieves a list of all the tab names

Currently, my code takes in the file ID and returns only the first tabs data as a df but not each tab individually. The code:

```
get_df_from_excel(creds, sheet_id):

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=sheet_id)
    file = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        df = pd.read_excel(file,  engine='openpyxl')
```

I am able to achieve this quite easily with gspread for google spreadsheets but handling .xlsx files is seemingly more difficult. Also, I use a service account to access the files. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=sheet_id)
file = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))
file.seek(0)
df = pd.read_excel(file, None)

print(df.keys()) # You can see sheet names.
print(df["Sheet2"]) # In this sample, the values are retrieved from "Sheet2".
```

- When this script is run, all sheet names are retrieved. And also, the values are retrieved from "Sheet2".